# Unable to search a file location

Tags: linux, centos

i am unable to locate files or directories while executing below commands. getting below error:

```
$ locate httpd
locate: can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory
```

Comment: For Centos it should be "updatedb" command.  Run it then you must wait for a while for the command to finish it's work. Also check your cronjob daily tasks if updatedb is there.

Comment: Run updatedb command, no changes made.

Comment: Well you have always alternatives in Linux. you can try "find" command. http://linux.die.net/man/1/find .. Eg:  find httpd -path / -print

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your locate database. This is usually a regular cron job. Different distros will have different tools. In FreeBSD it's `/etc/periodic/weekly/310.locate`

Answer (score 0):

You probably just installed the `mlocate` package and the database wasn't created/updated just yet. The package creates a cronjob at `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate.cron` that runs daily, but if you don't want to wait, you can just run `updatedb` first.